# Controls for displaying multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display a scrolling list of e-mails, the title in one column, the sender in other. DataGridView is far too clunky with all these headers and resizing. I'm looking for something like a list box, but one that could display multiple columns of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) with the [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property set to `Details`?

Comment: This looks fine. Is there an event triggered by clicking on the row in any place, not only on the first column?

Comment: Try setting the ListView's FullRowSelect property to true.  Does that meet your requirements?